# Webservice response time on dedicated tomcat webserver

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a `spring-boot` application whose webservice response time is `10ms` when running it as a `jar` with `embedded tomcat`.

But as soon as I deploy it on a dedicated `tomcat9` webserver, I'm getting response times from 80-100ms. Exactly the same application (just packaged as `war` instead of `jar`).

Question: how could I find the root cause of this problem? Or is it quite normal that a tomcat dedicated webserver is causing such delays? I have no proxies involved in between. The response times are measured from localhost to localhost with `curl`.